# Table recent performance degradation

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, vacuum

So on my current project we have an ETL process that on its final stage ends up writing about 35 million of records on table on a PostgreSQL database (PostGIS actually). The version we are currently using is version 11. The Database is a single node (no cluster or replication) and it is running on Google Cloud virtual machine.

The update process is as follows:

- We write the records using Upserts (`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... UPDATE ...`) inside a parallel process. 95% of the records are already there so the `UPDATE` is the most hit part.
- The `Autovacuum` is deactivated on the table so it does not interfere with the insertions.
- Once the insertions are done a manual `Vacuum` is run.
- After that there is a cluster index that is refreshed.

We have been running this process for about 3-4 months already and the performance fulfilled our requirements till 2 or 3 weeks ago that it started to degradate.

The table used to have 14 columns. One of it is a JSONB a and a Postgis type (geog). We don't know if it's related but have recently added a second JSONB that so far most of the time is empty. The table size it used to be 39GB and now with the new field (plus new records) is about 41-42GB.

Some numbers to show you de degradation:

- An analytical query that used to run on 10 minutes no takes 1 hour
- The table Vacuum used to run on half an hour now it takes 3 hours.
- Refreshing the cluster index used to take 35 minutes now is 6 hours!!!.
- We use to insert on a pace of 3-3.5K records per second. Now we are lucky if we get 1.5K records per second.

We have not tried to drop de table or a full Vacuum but before trying that we would like to know if there is any other solution or why this is suddenly happening.

### Edit 1

Laurenz below asked me for an execution so I could give you some clues of what is going on. I run the analytical query I mentioned above with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, TIMING)`. This is the plan obtained.

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=2720685.54..2720690.61 rows=20 width=23) (actual time=24366157.916..24366157.982 rows=19 loops=1)                                                                                                                   
  Group Key: pt.id                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  Buffers: shared hit=46163227 read=9073603 written=62544                                                                                                                                                                                          
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=2720685.54..2720690.21 rows=40 width=23) (actual time=24366157.907..24366220.682 rows=57 loops=1)                                                                                                                        
        Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        Buffers: shared hit=139174604 read=26543931 written=187102                                                                                                                                                                                 
        ->  Sort  (cost=2719685.51..2719685.56 rows=20 width=23) (actual time=24366137.746..24366137.748 rows=19 loops=3)                                                                                                                          
              Sort Key: pt.id                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB                                                                                                                                                                                                 
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB                                                                                                                                                                                      
              Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB                                                                                                                                                                                      
              Buffers: shared hit=139174604 read=26543931 written=187102                                                                                                                                                                           
              ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=2719684.88..2719685.08 rows=20 width=23) (actual time=24366137.642..24366137.647 rows=19 loops=3)                                                                                                   
                    Group Key: pt.id                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                    Buffers: shared hit=139174596 read=26543931 written=187102                                                                                                                                                                     
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=11355.31..2635662.02 rows=16804572 width=15) (actual time=20.557..24354046.499 rows=13444878 loops=3)                                                                                                     
                          Hash Cond: (ec.portfolio_id = pt.id)                                                                                                                                                                                     
                          Buffers: shared hit=139174596 read=26543931 written=187102                                                                                                                                                               
                          ->  Merge Join  (cost=11353.86..2582201.02 rows=16804572 width=4) (actual time=20.419..24337723.353 rows=13444878 loops=3)                                                                                               
                                Merge Cond: (et.comparable_id = ec.id)                                                                                                                                                                             
                                Buffers: shared hit=139174587 read=26543931 written=187102                                                                                                                                                         
                                ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using eco_transactions_comparable_id_date_out_operation_key on eco_transactions et  (cost=0.56..995953.14 rows=16804572 width=4) (actual time=3.576..764772.035 rows=13444878 loops=3)
                                      Heap Fetches: 37376815                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                      Buffers: shared hit=55847651 read=3538455 written=22950                                                                                                                                                      
                                ->  Index Scan using eco_comparables_pkey on eco_comparables ec  (cost=0.56..138981019.86 rows=37794812 width=8) (actual time=0.061..23532584.162 rows=37794543 loops=3)                                           
                                      Buffers: shared hit=83326936 read=23005476 written=164152                                                                                                                                                    
                          ->  Hash  (cost=1.20..1.20 rows=20 width=15) (actual time=0.060..0.060 rows=20 loops=3)                                                                                                                                  
                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB                                                                                                                                                                       
                                Buffers: shared hit=3                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                ->  Seq Scan on eco_portfolios pt  (cost=0.00..1.20 rows=20 width=15) (actual time=0.040..0.045 rows=20 loops=3)                                                                                                   
                                      Buffers: shared hit=3                                                                                                                                                                                        
Planning Time: 14.694 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Execution Time: 24366221.105 ms
```

Comment: Without seeing `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for some affected SQL statements, we know as little as you do.

Comment: Sorry Laurenz I did not answered you before. I needed to use the data on that table to do some actual work and because its recent slowness I could not find a time frame to run an explain. I'm updating the question with the execution plan you suggested.

Comment: All the time is spent in the index scan on `eco_comparables`. The 160000 blocks *written* by the scan suggest that the table has not been vacuumed recently. Try that and see if improves the query time. I don't know what columns you need from that table, but if there are not too many, you could `INCLUDE` them in the index to get a much faster index only scan. Independent of that advice, did you check if more `work_mem` improves the query?